# Double Dollar Sign - Assign Array key=>value

Tags: php, arrays, dollar-sign

I would like to create 3 different arrays which can change depending on which fields are pulled from some mysql tables.

This is the code I have:

```
    // Gather db rows with query
    $compQuery['subCats'] = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,category FROM subcategories ORDER BY id DESC");
    $compQuery['cats'] =    mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM categories ORDER BY id DESC");
    $compQuery['mans'] =    mysql_query("SELECT id,name,link FROM manufacturers ORDER BY id DESC");

    // Place rows into arrays
    foreach($compQuery as $name=>$query){

        $name = array();

        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($compQuery[$name])){
            foreach($data as $key=>$value){

                $$name[$key] = $value;                  

            }

        }

    }
```

What I would expect this to produce is 3 arrays: subCats, cats and mans each with the value pairs.  Instead of finding the $$name variable and assigning [$key] = $value to the array it is taking a single letter out of the $$name variable and assigning the $value to this new variable.

For example, if $name = 'subCats', $key = '3', and value = 'machine tools'

It would create the variable $C using the 3rd letter in subCats:

```
$C = 'machine tools'
```

What it should do is create:

```
$subCats[3] = 'machine tools';
```

Now, obviously there are easier ways to create separate arrays for each query, and I have modified my code to a lazier/easier version.  However, I am still curious as to how I would go about assigning a key value pair to a double dollar sign variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I have the simple code working now, but would like to implement this new code to be more dynamic and allow for more queries as needed without hassle.

Thanks!

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${$name}[$key]`

But I do not like to create 'unknown' variable, as in variables whose name is not in the code... What if the name is 'key','db','_GET','compQuery' etc? All hell breaks loose...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

I see what you mean though.  Any of these query names will be handled internally and have no reason to have to those variable names.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see no reason why they shouldn't be able to use `$result[$name]` instead of `$$name` all around, and it's a lot safer.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah that seems like a much better option.  This would also keep all of my query results grouped together and easier to reference.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
$name = array();
```

You're overwriting `$name`. You probably meant to write to `$$name`:

```
$$name = array();
```